# Sybase Advantage New AutoInc after SQL Insert

Tags: sybase, advantage-database-server

Anyone knows how to retrieve a new AutoInc that gets written after an ODBC INSERT?
Is there a variable I have access to just like SQL Server?
Right now, I'm using :

```
SELECT MAX(myautoincfield) AS mylastkey FROM anytable
```

in order to retrieve my new key.

Answer (score 4):

The scalar function [`LastAutoinc`](https://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10/master_miscellaneous_functions.htm) can retrieve it efficiently:

```
select LastAutoinc(statement) as mylastkey from system.iota;
```

Answer (score 0):

The global variable @@identity identifies the last value inserted into an IDENTITY column by the current session.

You may do the following:

```
select @@identity
```

in order to retrieve the new key.